# Regex to extract digits and dots from a string

Tags: php, regex, extract, digits

I'm using the following code to extract the version number from a string. The version number is the first match made only by digits and dots. For example in the string: "GT-I9000M-user 2.25.31 FROYO UGKC1 release-keys" the match would be: "2.25.31"
Another example in string: "1.24.661.1hbootpreupdate:13DelCache: 1" the match would be: "1.24.661.1".

My current code is:

```
if (preg_match('/[\d]+[\.][\d]+/', $version, $matches)) { 
    return $matches[0]; //returning the first match 
}
```

This code fits only some of the cases but not all of them. For example in the first example it will only return: "2.25" instead of "2.25.31". In the second example it will return "1.24" instead of "1.24.661.1".

I'm new to RegEx so I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Jsut a tip: you need not `[]` here, because you use only 1 symbol in it. Besides, You need not to escape `.` by `\`` in `[]` You regexp is eqiualent to \d+\.\d+

Comment: @RiaD I thought the dot needed escaping because it can replace any single character. Is that not the case when you use it inside a class?

Comment: No reasons to use symbols `all characters` inside a class because class will be `all characters` anyway. so `print preg_match('~.~','x');
print preg_match('~[.]~','x');` prints 10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/\d+(?:\.\d+)+/', $version, $matches)) { 
    return $matches[0]; //returning the first match 
}
```

Allow the `.x` to repeat and it should work.

Comment: why did you add the '?:' part? What does it mean in this context?

Comment: it makes the sub-pattern non capturing (it won't be returned in $matches)

Comment: @arnaud576875 I'm not sure what you mean by that. In $matches[0] I get exactly the same thing like when I use '/\d+(\.\d+)+/' ...

Comment: @Ran Without the `?:`, `$matches[1]` would contain the part inside the parentheses. It's called a capture group. Since you don't need that information, the `?:` makes it a non-capturing group.

Comment: It does not match version numbers without dots. (in case someone need that)

Comment: `$matches[0]` always contains the entire string that matched the entire regex. `$matches[1]` would contain the string that matched the first capturing group sub-pattern. In the answer above there is no capturing group sub-pattern. As a result `$matches[1]` would be null, or more likely out of range.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
'/\d+(\.\d+)+/'
```

The difference with yours is that it allows the `.\d+` part to repeat, thus allowing multiple dots.

Answer (score 0):

To match software version numbers with one/without/multiple dots one could use:

```
\d+(?:\.*\d*)*
```

(kudos to authors before this post)